# Get flatlist items positions coordinates

Tags: react-native

I have the next scenario: FlatList component contains item with video and when video component in the center it has to start to play video. Is there any way to get coordinates while I am scrolling and then count that item in the center. onViewableItemsChanged doesn't help only data for item is provided.

Comment: onViewableItemsChanged gives you a list of viewable items. How about you take the middle element of the provided list of viewable items (if 3 elements, take the 2nd element of that array) and based on its key, use ref and play that video? Worth a try, I'd say.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.